# Where to send rescue on HomePage controller?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, ruby-on-rails-3

I have a homepage and a controller called `StaticPagescontroller`.

I used a rescue (as you see below) but an error on the page showed me it was a bad idea, or at least I was doing it the wrong way.
Any problem on the homepage triggers the rescue that points to the root_page which is the homepage, giving me an infinite loop that was blocking everything, which was a bad idea!

What's the best practice?

What should I do with `rescue` on the homepage?

Should I point it to a 404 page? To something else?

```
class StaticPagesController < ApplicationController

  def home
    @deals = Deal.featured.to_a 

    rescue  
    redirect_to authenticated_root_path
  end
```

Comment: This piece of code shall not raise an error unless you coded it wrong. Deal.featured.to_a should always work in every situation, no need for a rescue here. If you are looking for a way to handle 404 & friends, see this blog post http://blog.yangtheman.com/2012/10/11/user-friendly-500-and-404-pages-on-rails-3/ -- bonne chance ;)

Comment: the code was wrong due to sth i did in another file but i don't think it's a good practice , even in ase of error, to make a page point to itself: it was creating a loop

Comment: the rescue has nothing to do here, that's all. This page should not redirect you if there is an error, it should just crash to make you fix it. It's a "StaticPage" as you called it. Not an API call or a complex logic or cross-domain action

Answer (score 0):

When an error happens I like to fist log the error and then redirect to a 404 page.

This is how I do it.

```
class StaticPagesController < ApplicationController
  def home
    @deals = Deal.featured.to_a 
    rescue => error
    handle_error(error)  
  end
end
```

now my ApplicationController would look something like this

```
class ApplicationController < ActionController::Base
  def handle_error(error)  
    Error.create(error)
    format.html { render :file => "#{Rails.root}/public/404", :layout => false, :status => :not_found }
  end
end
```

a good thing to know is that the files in the public directory render before rails server starts so they can still render.

I hope that this helps